# What is the difference between MVB UMVUE and MVUE.?

Tags: estimation, inference, unbiased-estimator, inequality, rao-blackwell

Cramer Rao inequality gives MVB and if MVB exist it is MLE.

Rao Blackwell gives UMVUE, but isn’t when we have MVB estimator for unbiased it is UMVUE?

Then what is MVUE?

MVB minimum variance bound
UMVUE Uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator
MVUE Minimum variance unbiased estimator
MLE maximum likelihood estimator

Comment: Could you write out all those abbreviations.

Comment: CR inequality relates to the Cramér-Rao bound?

Comment: When I fill in those abbreviations then the sentence makes no sense *"Cramer Rao inequality gives minimum variance bound  and if minimum variance bound  exist it is maximum likelihood estimator.*"